# Proving that the Union of Two Compact Sets is Compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Prove if $S_1,S_2$ are compact, then their union $S_1\cup S_2$ is compact as well.

The attempt at a proof:

Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are compact, every open cover contains a finite subcover. Let the open cover of $S_1$ and $S_2$ be $\mathscr{F}_1$ and $\mathscr{F}_2$, and let the finite subcover of $\mathscr{F}_1$ and $\mathscr{F}_2$ be $\mathscr{G}_1$ and $\mathscr{G}_2$, respectively. If I can show that $S_1\cup S_2$ contains a finite subcover for every open cover, then I will have showed that the union is indeed compact. I note that $\mathscr{G}_1\subset\mathscr{F}_1$ and that $\mathscr{G}_2\subset\mathscr{F}_2$ (by definition of an open subcover). Then, I note that $\mathscr{G}_1\subset\mathscr{F}_1\cup\mathscr{F}_2$ and that $\mathscr{G}_2\subset\mathscr{F}_1\cup\mathscr{F}_2.$

I'm not sure how to proceed from this point. I think I am on the right track though. Any suggestions to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "$S$ is compact" does not mean "there is an open cover $F$ of $S$ such that $F$ has a finite subcover" but rather it means "for every open cover $F$ of $S$, $F$ has a finite subcover".

Comment: So your proof should begin "let $F$ be an open cover of $S_1 \cup S_2$" and proceed to find a finite subset of $F$ that covers $S_1 \cup S_2$.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

HINT: You’re starting in the wrong place. In order to show that $S_1\cup S_2$ is compact, you should start with an arbitrary open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $S_1\cup S_2$ and show that it has a finite subcover. The hypothesis that $\mathscr{U}$ covers $S_1\cup S_2$ simply means that $S_1\cup S_2\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$. Clearly this implies that $S_1\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ and $S_2\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$. Thus, $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $S_1$ and also an open cover of $S_2$. Now use the compactness of $S_1$ and $S_2$ to produce a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $S_1\cup S_2$.

Comment: Would producing this finite sub cover of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $S_{1} \cup S_{2}$ go something like: Since $S_{1}$ is compact there exists a finite sub cover $\mathscr{C}_{1}$ of $\mathscr{U}$ and since $S_{2}$ is compact there exists a finite sub cover $\mathscr{C}_{2}$ of $\mathscr{U}$ such that  $S_{1} \cup S_{2} \subset \bigcup (\mathscr{C}_{1} \cup \mathscr{C}_{2})$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, you get a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ that covers $S_1$ and another that covers $S_2$, and their union is still finite and covers $S_1\cup S_2$.

Comment: Great! does a similar argument work for intersections of compact sets? I read somewhere that "The intersection of any number of compact sets is a closed subset any of the sets, and therefore compact" for arbitrary metric space; I'm not sure I believe this though.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is always closed, a closed subset of any compact set is compact, and the intersection of closed sets is always closed. Thus, the intersection of compact sets in a Hausdorff space is an intersection of closed sets, so it’s closed, and it’s a subset of a compact set, so it’s compact.

Answer (score 7):

Start with an open cover of the union. For $i=1,2$ it is also an open cover of $S_{i}$. These are compact so there are finite subcovers. The union of these subcovers is a finite subcover of the union.

Answer (score 6):

Every open cover of the union is an open cover of each set.
So for each set there is a finite subcover.
The union of the finite subcover is still finite and covers the union of the two sets.
So the union is indeed compact.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have an open cover of $S_1 \cup S_2$. Since they are separately compact, there is a finite open cover for each. Then combine the finite covers, this will still be finite. Hence the union is compact,