# Union of Two Compact Sets is Compact

Tags: general-topology

So Im aware this question has been asked already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538429/proving-that-the-union-of-two-compact-sets-is-compact).

However, the definition of compactness for a subset I am following is slightly different and I am struggling to translate the top answer for the question to suit my definition.

The definition I am following is:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $S\subseteq X$. Then $S$ is a compact set if $S$ with the subspace topology is a compact topological space.

The problem is that this definition means that if $\mathscr{U}$ is a cover of $S_1\cup S_2$ then $S_1\cup S_2=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ as appose to $S_1\cup S_2\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ and so I don't know how deduce that $\mathscr{U}$ is open cover for $S_1$ and for $S_2$

Comment: you are using the same definition. you just need to recall what is the subspace topology

Comment: I know that the subspace topology will help me argue that $\mathscr{U}$ is open but I don't know how it will help me argue that it is a cover of $S_1$ and $S_2$ individually.

Comment: The way I see it is that I need $\mathscr{U}$ to be cover of $S_1$ and of $S_2$ but this would mean $S_1=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ but $\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ will also cover points in $S_2$, which may not be in $S_1$

Comment: Notice that you have 3 subsets. Probably you should start by asking yourself what is the subspace topology for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal U$ be a (relative, in the subspace topology of $S$) open cover 
of $S=S_1\cup S_2$. For each $U\in\mathcal U$ fix $U'$ open in $X$ with $U=U'\cap S$. 
Let $\mathcal U_1=\{U'\cap S_1:U\in\mathcal U\}$ and $\mathcal U_2=\{U'\cap S_2:U\in\mathcal U\}$. Then $\mathcal U_1$ is a (relative) open cover of $S_1$ and hence has a finite subcover $\{V_1,\dots,V_n\}$. Similarly, $\mathcal U_2$ is a (relative) open cover of $S_2$ and hence has a finite subcover $\{W_1,\dots,W_m\}$. For each $j=1,\dots,n$ fix $U(1,j)\in\mathcal U$ with $V_j=U'(1,j)\cap S_1$. For each $k=1,\dots,m$ fix $U(2,k)\in\mathcal U$ with $W_k=U'(2,k)\cap S_2$. Verify that $\{U(1,j):j=1,\dots,n\}$ together with $\{U(2,k):k=1,\dots,m\}$ is a finite (relatively) open cover of $S$ (and it is a subcover of $\mathcal U$).

Comment: this makes more sense because you don't claim that $\mathcal U$ is a cover for BOTH $S_1$ and $S_2$ but that part of $\mathcal U$ covers $S_1$ and another part covers $S_2$ and thats the part I was confused about

Comment: Yes, though I would not use the word *part* of $\mathcal U$ (since the word part for me would suggest subfamily, which is not the case above). I would like to think of $\mathcal U_1$ as the *restriction*, or *relativization* of $\mathcal U$ to $S_1$, indeed notice that we also have $\mathcal U_1=\{U\cap S_1:U\in\mathcal U\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $S_1\cup S_2=:S$. This $S$ is a subspace of the base space $X$. An open cover of $S$ consists of a collection $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ of open subsets of $S$ whose union contains $S$. By definition of the subspace topology this means that there are open sets $\tilde U_\alpha\subset X$ such that each $U_\alpha=\tilde U_\alpha\cap S$, and one has
$$S\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha\subset \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\tilde U_\alpha\ .$$
The $\tilde U_\alpha$ together contain both $S_1$ and $S_2$. It follows that the $U_\alpha^1:=\tilde U_\alpha\cap S_1$ together contain $S_1$. Since $S_1$ is assumed compact there is a finite subcover $$S_1\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^N U^1_{\alpha_k}\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^N\tilde U_{\alpha_k}\ .$$ Similarly one has
$$S_2\subset\bigcup_{k=N+1}^M U^2_{\alpha_k}\subset \bigcup_{k=N+1}^M\tilde U_{\alpha_k}\ .$$
In this way we obtain
$$S=S_1\cup S_2\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^M\tilde U_{\alpha_k}\ .$$
It is then easily seen that 
$$S\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^M U_{\alpha_k}\subset S\ ,$$
as required.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding the step where you say the union of $\tilde U_\alpha$ covers both $S_1$ and $S_2$ because to me this would mean that both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are equal to $\bigcup \tilde U_\alpha$