Prove that $\operatorname*{\bigcup}_{i=1}^{n}[a_i,b_i]$ equals the union of finitely many disjoint closed bounded intervals.


Exercise 2.5.14 from 'The Real Numbers and Real Analysis' by Ethan D.
Bloch.

Hello, today I tried to prove this statement, but I'm stuck so I would like some help. Below I will put a drawing that more or less expresses the idea I had when making the proof for the second case, in this way I hope to give more clarity to some definitions.

Solution. Let $P_n$ be the statement that a union of $n$ closed bounded intervals can be written as a  union of closed bounded disjoint intervals. Clearly, $P_1$ is true. Suppose $P_{k}$ is true. Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}[a_i,b_i]=\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ where the intervals $[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ are disjoint for all $i \in \{1,\cdots,m\}$ (IH). Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}[a_i,b_i] &= \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}[a_i,b_i]\right )\cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}] \\
    &= \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{m}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right )\cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}].
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
We proceed by cases.
Case 1. Suppose that $[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\cap[\alpha_i,\beta_i]=\varnothing$ for all $i \in \{1,\cdots,m\}$. Then by (IH) and the previous equation we conclude that $P_{k+1}$ is true.
Case 2. Suppose that $[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\cap[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\neq\varnothing$ for some $i' \in \{1,\cdots,m\}$. Let
$$I:=\{i\in \{1,\cdots,m\}:[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\cap[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\neq\varnothing\},$$
and let
$$J:=\{1,\cdots,m\}-I.$$
Then we have that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right)\cup[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}] &= \left ( \bigcup_{i\in \{1,\cdots,m\}}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right )\cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}] \\
    &=  \left(\left(\bigcup_{i\in J}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right)\right) \cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\\
    &= \left(\bigcup_{i\in J}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right)\cup\left(\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]\right) \cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\right)\\
    &= I_J\cup \left(I_I\cup[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\right),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $I_J:=\bigcup_{i\in J}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ and $I_I:=\bigcup_{i\in I}[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$. We prove that  $I_J\cap \left(I_I \cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\right)=\varnothing$. By (IH) we know that $I_I\cap I_J = \varnothing$. So let $x \in I_J$, then $x \in [\alpha_j,\beta_j]$ for some $j\in J$ . Hence $j\notin I$, and thus $[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\cap[\alpha_j,\beta_j]=\varnothing$. Consequently $x \notin [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]$. Furthermore, assume that $x \in [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]$. If $x \notin [\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ for all $i\in \{1\cdots,m\}$, then $x\notin I_J$. If $x \in [\alpha_j,\beta_j]$ for some $j\in \{1\cdots,m\}$, then $[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\cap[\alpha_j,\beta_j]\neq\varnothing$. So $j \in I$. Consequently $j\notin J$, and so $x\notin I_J$. Therefore $I_J\cap \left(I_I \cup [a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\right)=\varnothing$.
Finally, we show that
$I_I\cup[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]=[\alpha,\beta]$,
where $\alpha:=\text{min}\{a_{k+1},\text{min}\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}\}$ and $\beta:=\text{max}\{b_{k+1},\text{max}\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}\}$. Let $x\in I_I\cup[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]$. Then either $x \in [\alpha_j,\beta_j]$ for some $j\in I$, and so
$$\alpha \leq \text{min}\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I} \leq \alpha_j \leq x\leq \beta_j \leq \text{max}\{\beta_i\}_{i\in I}\leq \beta,$$
or
$$\alpha\leq a_{k+1}\leq x\leq b_{k+1}\leq \beta.$$
Therefore we conclude that $x\in[\alpha,\beta]$.

Edit: I modified the original proof to make it more similar to the
solution proposed by @geetha290krm. It is still incomplete.


Not much needs to be done here. If any two of the given intervals intersect, then you can replace the two intervals by a single interval (without changing the question). In a finite number of steps, you can write the given union as a disjoint union.

So you suggest doing an algorithmic proof?

You've had a solid idea! (+1) Unfortunately, you seem to have gotten off track by basing your induction on the cardinality of a finite subset of a specific finite set of intervals. The approach outlined in the answer given by @geetha290krm, based instead on the cardinality of an arbitrary finite set of such intervals, is the one you want.

I feel like this question involves topology.

Hi @CameronBuie, I'm not very familiar with the term 'cardinality' except for the fact that it represents the size of a set, but from what I understand from your comment is that the statement $P_n$ is given in a more general sense so to speak, so it makes the proof easier. is that what you are referring to?

Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Here is completely rigorous alternative proof: Let $P_n$ be the statement that a union of $n$ closed bounded intervals can be written as a  union of closed bounded disjoint intervals. Clearly, $P_1$ is true. Suppose $P_{n}$ is true. Consider $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} [a_i,b_i]$. If $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ is disjoint from all the previous intervals, you just have to apply $P_{n}$  to $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} [a_i,b_i]$ to finish the proof. Suppose $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ intersects $[a_k ,b_k]$. Then, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} [a_i,b_i]$ can be written as  union of $n$ closed bounded intervals by replacing $[a_k,b_k]\cup [a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ by  a single interval. We are now in a  position to use $P_{n}$ again to finish the proof.

If $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ intersects more than one interval $[a_k ,b_k]$, it shouldn't be a problem as long the number of intervals is greater than or equal to 1 based on the statement $P_n$?

Yes, that is correct. @J.J.G

I think it is wrong to say that the union of $n+1$ closed bounded intervals can be written as the union of $n$ closed bounded intervals because this is only correct in the case where only one interval $[a_i,b_i]$ intersects $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$, so, shouldn't it be "can be written as the union of $k$ closed bounded intervals where $1\leq\ k\leq n$ by performing the union of all the sets $[a_i,b_i]$ that intersect with $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$"?

@J.J.G your concern is understandable, but note that the claim is not saying that "$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}[a_i,b_i]$ can be written as the union of $n$ disjoint closed bounded intervals." Does that clear things up?

@CameronBuie Yes, now I understand. Your proof is very clever indeed!

@J.J.G it's not my proof, but I certainly agree!

Denote $S=\bigcup_{k=1}^n[a_k,b_k].$ For two points $x,y\in S$ we say $x\sim y$ if the  closed interval between $x$ and $y$ is contained in $S.$ Then $"\sim"$ is an equivalence relation. The set $S$ is  the union of disjoint equivalence classes. Each class is a closed interval.

Isn't this (plus the fact that there are at most $n$ classes)  the same as my cw answer?

@AnneBauval It is the same indeed. I wanted to  avoid first of all the induction method, secondly the definitions of connectedness, connected componenents, to make the answer down to earth. Not all users are comfortable with connectedness property for general topological spaces.

I think what you miss is that you should use second form of induction rather than first form. That is, assume $P(n)$ for all $n\le k$, and then induct to $n=k+1$
I think that would do the trick for you.
That is:
Assume $\bigcup_{i=1}^n [a_i,b_i]$ equals the union of finitely many disjoint closed and bounded intervals for all $n\le k,k>2$.
That is, $P(n)$ for all $n\le k$.
Then, we ought to prove on $n=k+1$.
So $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}[a_i,b_i]=[a_{k+1},b_{k+1}]\cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}[a_i,b_i]$$
Since $k\le k, P(k)$ holds, therefore $\bigcup_{i=1}^k[a_i,b_i]$ is a union of finitely many disjoint closed interval.
Then, since $[a_i,b_i]$ are closed and bounded, we have that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k [a_i,b_i]$ is closed and bounded.[1] And since that $2\le k$,$P(2)$ holds. Therefore, our exercise' statement follows!
[1]: closed and bounded sets are called compact sets, finite union of compact sets are also compact. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/538435/1322489

This is immediate from the two following facts:

The connected components of a space are disjoint and closed.
The connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are the intervals.

